# Vuex mapState set State

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuex

In my store I have...

```
...
  addresses: [ /* array of address objects */ ],
  address: { /* holds chosen address */ }
...
```

In my component, I have...

```
    import {mapState, mapActions} from 'vuex'

      export default {
        name: 'AddressBook',
        watch: {
          selectedAddress: function(newval) {
            // Update the address
            // address and addresses is mapped from the vuex store.
            this.address = Object.assign( this.address, this.addresses[newval]);
          }
        },
        data: {
          selectedAddress: 0 /* Address selected by index */
        }
        computed: {
          ...mapState(['addresses', 'address'])
        }
      }
```

Addresses and Address are being mapped from vuex.
User chooses an address from a select box of addresses (eg addresses[1])... which is used to update the address.

The thing that has confused me is that updating this.address this way just works... My Vuex store changes. I thought I'd have to dispatch / commit etc..? It just seems too simple.. too easy..

Is it safe to update this.address in this way, at the component level?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it safe to update this.address in this way, at the component level?

No, at the very least you should be committing changes from a mutation (or calling an action that commits a mutation). From the [Mutations documentation](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/mutations.html):

> The only way to actually change state in a Vuex store is by committing a mutation.

Also, the way you're modifying address might not be happening how you might think:

```
this.address = Object.assign( this.address, this.addresses[newval]);
```

It's nonsensical (maybe impossible? not sure if Vue freezes) to re-assign a computed property like this anyway. What's actually happening is `Object.assign` always mutates the first parameter directly. That's why you might often see the empty-object pattern e.g. `Object.assign({}, this.address, this.addresses[newval])`

At any rate, to avoid subtle accidental mutations like this, you can enable [strict mode](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/strict.html) which will warn you when those unsafe mutations happen.

Comment: Thanks - I thought it was too simple :) I've mapped the Mutations to my component methods, and added this.UPDATE_ADDRESS(this.addresses[newval]);